# What is the problem with the following regex?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have to group the following statement into 3 groups:

> ```
> DFFX1 _pcpi_insn_reg_16_  ( .D(n13328), .CK(clk), .Q(pcpi_insn_16_) );
> ```

```
Group1: DFFX1
Group2: _pcpi_insn_reg_16_
Group3:  .D(n13328), .CK(clk), .Q(pcpi_insn_16_)
```

I am using: `(.*) (.*) \((.*)\);`

The output is:

```
Group1: DFFX1 _pcpi_insn_reg_16_
Group2: *empty*
Group3:  .D(n13328), .CK(clk), .Q(pcpi_insn_16_)
```

Can you please explain why is this not working?

Comment: I tested this here: https://regex101.com/r/swxskr/1 and your regex works fine, so your problem is probably somewhere else in your code. Please add more code/context which is linked to this regex.

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I've updated the question. Since the example was in a quote block the double space between `_pcpi_insn_reg_16_` and `(` wasn't visible. The text to parse is now in a code block to prevent double space removal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because by default regular expressions are greedy.  In other words the first `.*` will consume as much of the target text is it can before yielding to the second one.  You should make your pattern more restrictive to account for this.  For example:

```
import re

pattern = r'([\S]+) ([\S]+) \((.*)\)'
text = 'DFFX1 _pcpi_insn_reg_16_ ( .D(n13328), .CK(clk), .Q(pcpi_insn_16_) );'

m = re.match(pattern, text)
print m.groups()
```

Instead of matching on any character, this only matches on characters that are not a whitespace character (that's what `\S` does).  This will print these groups:

```
('DFFX1', '_pcpi_insn_reg_16_', ' .D(n13328), .CK(clk), .Q(pcpi_insn_16_) ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The Regex can be made more restrictive to work:

```
'(\w*)\s(\w*)\s\((.*)\)'
```